# High Available service - IP/DNS single point of failure

Tags: high-availability, redundancy

I'm looking for High Available solution for websites and already find
Kubernates , Docker Swarm ... but all these things should balance only webserver , db and other running service in the cluster. But what about the IP addresses DNS.
Let's assume that I decide to use Docker Swarm , and create nodes in 3 independent hosting providers: AWS , Digital Ocean , Rackspace or something else.. then I have my websites replicated on 3 locations and all sounds perfect, but in same moment something need to direct the visitors to my servers, for this   purpose probably I have to use Round robin DNS (A record which to point to the 3 IPs). What if one of my nodes fail? The DNS still will point to there and some of visitors will not be able to connect. Please let me know what are the solutions in this case. Probably Round robin DNS is not the only required for HA services.

Assume that AWS ELB or DO LB going down, because some bad people decide to send them few hundred Gbits flood :) My point is what is best solution to keep HA in case of LB fail by some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your DNS to point to dedicated load balancers from your provider (ELB in AWS and the newly introduced load balancers in DO), then those LBs will direct traffic to your functional nodes.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to handle this:

- Use DNS provider with active monitoring, who can disable your backend if it is unreachable (still not perfect, but better than nothing)
- Build your own anycast network and let your IP range to propagate from different datacetners

If I can give you my personal opinion - don't do either of them. Cloud services are reliable these days enough. Even google/facebook goes down time to time ...